# Tomcat Warning : Cannot serialize session attribute ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.SearchService

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat8, catalina

**Should I implement Serializable Interface to resolve the issue?**

Error Log :

> 05-May-2016 10:34:16.644 WARNING
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject **Cannot
>   serialize session attribute
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.searchController**
>   for session CAA037423C1AEEB003C4B67ED1F34CFF
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   **com.shoptell.frontoffice.rest.SearchController** at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject(StandardSession.java:1710)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:401)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:320)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:487)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5400)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:827)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1407)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1333)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1555)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:285)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1141)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Code :

```
@Scope("session")
@RestController
public class SearchController {
/** methods **/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try make SearchController Serializable:

```
@Scope("session")
@RestController
public class SearchController implements Serializable {
/** methods **/
}
```